# LibreOffice Writer: how to have table cell-text visible over horisontal adjacent cells

Tags: libreoffice-writer

[image]

LibreOffice Writer: for example, 3x3 table, with text in cell "A1".
How can I allow for a text, longer than the table cell it is placed in, to be visible on one line, so adjacent cell does not hide the text.
It seems that as a standard the text in the table-cells are word wrapped, but i would like to have the text shown on one line so it extends over the cells to the right.

I know i could Merge the three top cells to hold the length of the text, but would relly like to leave the cell structure the same in the table.

Hope anyone knows if ther is a function or trick for this! :)

Thanks, David.

Comment: The text from A1 will "flow" over B1 and C1 **if** B1 / C1 are empty, otherwise it will be truncated. AFAIK there's no way to change this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! :) 

However my B1/C1 cells are empty, but the text still does not show after it passes cell border! ??

Anyway, i can merge the cells as a solution! Thanks!